# Is there a way of saving the isochrone maps generated in OSMnx?

Tags: python, gis, osmnx

I would like to save the output of the isochrone maps as a shapefile.

I am following the example here:

https://geoffboeing.com/2017/08/isochrone-maps-osmnx-python/

And have tried the arguments here:

https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx

But can't get it to save.

e.g. for `ox.save_load.save_graph_shapefile` I get:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'edges'

and for `ox.save_load.save_gdf_shapefile`, I get:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'edges'

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a code snippet or MWE, so I'll guess at what you've done so far with a suggestion of how to proceed. In cell 8 in [this notebook](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/13-isolines-isochrones.ipynb), which it seems you're working off of, a list of polygon isochrones is generated. You can just create a [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) geoseries from this list, then save that to disk as a shapefile.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for that. I should have noticed that earlier. By the way, very useful package.